# How does a if statment condtional work on non-bool types?

Tags: c++

IE how does the if statement know what to call when it checks a particular object? Say we have

```
if (std::cin) doSomething();
```

C++ calls `std::cin.good()`. What is the mechanism that tells C++ to call the `good` function?

Comment: For future reference, the google input I used to find the duplicate: how does if cin work? site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does a if statment condtional work on non-bool types?

The result of the expression is converted to bool.

For class types, the conversion is achieved through the conversion operator - primarily the `bool` conversion operator, or in its absence, possibly conversion to a type that has non-user defined conversion to `bool`, such as integer or pointer.